# getting undefined while exporting object in java script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, web-development-server

i have created a separate file for the database management in my web app, the data is getting fetched perfectly but when i am trying to export the the object it is giving undefined

I am using **express** and **mongoose**

```
exports.getAll=function(){
   Item.find({},(err,result)=>{
       if(err){
           console.log(err)
           return err
       }else{
           return result
       }
   })
}
```

```
app.get("/result",(req,res)=>{

   res.send(db.getAll())
})
```

when i am console loging the `db.getAll()` function im getting undefined and thus even i send it to the browser no data is getting passed.

Comment: const db = require(__dirname+"/database.js")

Answer (score 0):

`getAll()` does not `return` anything, that is why its result is `undefined`. Those `return`s you have are inside the callback function, but most likely that is not expected to return anything, `find()` just discards what it gets.

I do not know for sure, but the functionality you want probably should look like this:

```
exports.getAll=function(callback){
  Item.find({},(err,result)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      callback(err);
    }else{
      callback(result);
    }
  });
};
```

---

```
app.get("/result",(req,res)=>{
  db.getAll(data=>res.send(data));
});
```

Comment: data is not defined is getting passed as the response

Comment: @SouvikDe sorry, I typed that on phone, `data=res.send(data)` was meant to be an arrow function, `data=>res.send(data)` (fixed it now).

Comment: i sent the res and req function and now it is working fine. thanks for the idea